# Solving an equation for two primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, diophantine-equations

This is from contest preparation:

> Find all pairs of primes $(p, q)$ that satisfy
>
> $$p^q - q^p = p q^2 - 19$$.

It looks simple, but I spent hours trying to solve it... and no luck so far.

NOTE: There are similar MSE Q&Ąs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474768/diophantine-equation-involving-prime-numbers-p3-q5-pq2?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384066/number-theory-prime-powers-and-cubes?rq=1). Perhaps someone could apply some ideas from there.

Comment: Maybe one can use Fermat's Theorem and (cases $p\lt q$ and $q\lt p$) grind it out. I have not done details, it could be computationally hideous, but it is a finite problem.

Comment: **Hint:** The difference $|p^q-q^p|$ grows exponentially with regard to $|p-q|$ for $\min(p,q)$ greater than a certain value, so if we'd want to minimize it so as to make it fit in the order of $pq^2$ or $p^2q$, we'd have to either take $p\approx q$, or else give very small values to one of them. In the first case, by the time we reach $10$, the difference between the two sides is astronomical. In the latter situation, their minimum can be no more than $5$. This can be easily checked by computer by running a **for** cycle for $2\le p,q\le20$.

Comment: @Lucian, yeah, I like the approach, actually I tried it but could come up with strict reasoning... Thanks, if you have time, maybe you can attach full answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a diophantine equation involving prime numbers. Therefore it makes sense to try to solve the problem with the help of techniques and theorems from this particular field of mathematics. I refer to the answer posted by Hagen von Eitzen.

However, we can also see the problem as a fairly simple math puzzle, and solve it with common sense and elementary mathematical considerations.

The right hand side of the equation has a cubic term and a constant. The left hand side has two terms with (in general) much higher powers. So if we plug in some random values, e.g. $p=7$ and $q=11$, then the absolute value of the LHS will be many orders of magnitude larger than the RHS. Even when the difference between $p$ and $q$ is minimal, the LHS increases much more rapidly than the RHS. Thus there is a strict limit on the maximum value for the smallest of the pair $(p, q)$.

It turns out that $3$ is the critical value. However if we try $(p,q) = (3,5)$, then the LHS is already too large. This effect only increases for larger $q$. From this we conclude that there can be only be solutions if the smallest value equals $2$. [In fact there is also a solution $p=1$ and $q=4$, but these are not prime numbers.]

Case 1. $p=2$. This leads to the equation $f = 2^q - 3q^2 + 19 = 0$. We can easily verify that the function has (roughly) a parabolic shape, and thus there are at maximum two solutions. These are indeed found for $q=3$ and $q=7$.

Case 2. $q=2$. This leads to the equation $g = 2^p -p^2 + 4p -19 = 0$. This function appears to be monotonically increasing. So there is at most one solution. We can verify that $g$ has indeed a zero for a real value of $p$ larger than $4$, smaller than $5$. It follows that there are no solutions where $p$ is a natural number (prime).

Comment: Good answer, though could be improved by supplying some proofs (or sketches) for what you claim (how big the LHS gets and why this gives that particular upper bound on $p,q$)

Answer (score 10):

Certainly $p\ne q$ (as we cannot have $pq^2-19=0$).

Consider the equation modulo $p$ and $q$, using Fermat's little theorem:
$$ -q\equiv -19\pmod p$$
$$ p\equiv -19\pmod q$$
Hence $$-19\equiv p-q\pmod{pq}.$$
Let $p-q=kpq-19$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$. With $p=2$ we arrive at $(2k+1)q=21$, so $q=3$ or $q=7$. This gives us two candidate solutions $(p,q)=\color{red}{(2,3)}$ and  $(p,q)=\color{red}{(2,7)}$. Assume from now on that $p\ge 3$. Especially, $(kp+1)q=p+19$ is a positive even number, hence $kp+1$ must be positive even, i.e., $k$ is positive odd.

- The case $k=1$ is only possible with
  $$ p-2\ge p-q=pq-19\ge 2p-19,$$
  i.e., $p\le 17$. For each of $p=3,5,7,11,13,17$, check if $q=\frac{p+19}{p+1} $ is prime. This leads to $(p,q)=\color{red}{(17,2)}$.
- The case  $k=3$ is only possible with
  $$ p-2\ge p-q=3pq-19\ge 6p-19,$$
  i.e., $5p\le 17$ and finally $p=3$. However, then $q=\frac{p+19}{3p+1}$ fails to be prime.
- If $k\ge 5$, we find 
  $$ p-2\ge p-q=kpq-19\ge 10p-19,$$
  i.e., $9p\le 17$, which is impossible.

Check the original equation with the solution candidates found.

Comment: I would like to point out that there is another solution: $(p,q) = (2,3)$.

Comment: @M.Wind Thnaks for pointing this out.I implicitly assumed that $pq>19$ / forgot to mention that one should check these finitely many cases manually. Thanks to your comment, I reorganized the proof suitably.

Comment: You made a small mistake. Okay. These things happen. I have no respect for "the community" though. Blindly upvoting your answer, without checking its validity. Dismissing my simpler, but equally effective approach which leads straight to the correct answer. Morons!